# a bug in findutils about case insensitive?

Tags: regex, gnu-findutils

There is a file named `foo.js` in the current folder.

I use find to search :

```
tigerlei::~/work $ ll foo.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tigerlei tigerlei 187 Mar 29  2017 foo.js

tigerlei::~/work $ find . -regex '.*/foo.*.j[R-T]+' -regextype egrep
./foo.js

tigerlei::~/work $ find . -regex '.*/foo.*.j[RST]+' -regextype egrep

tigerlei::~/work $ find . -iregex '.*/foo.*.j[RST]+' -regextype egrep
./foo.js
```

My system is ubuntu 14.04.

findutil's version is 4.4.2

When I use `-regex`, find will use case sensitive mode. But:

- `[R-T]` will match the lowercase letter 's', and
- `[RST]` will not match 's'.

**Question**

Why are those outcomes the results of my searches?

Comment: Looks like collation issue, use `LC_ALL=C`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do

Comment: Thank you very much . after using LC_ALL=C the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `LC_ALL=C` to ensure the characters that form the range in the bracket expression go in the same order as in the ASCII table.

See [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763):

> If you mean to match a letter in the user's language, use `grep '[[:alpha:]]'` and don't modify `LC_ALL`. But if you want to match the `a-zA-Z` ASCII characters, you need either `LC_ALL=C grep '[[:alpha:]]'` or `LC_ALL=C grep '[a-zA-Z]'`. `[a-z]` matches the characters that sort after `a` and before `z` (though with many APIs it's more complicated than that). In other locales, you generally don't know what those are. For instance some locales ignore case for sorting so `[a-z]` in some APIs like bash patterns, could include `[B-Z]` or `[A-Y]`. In many UTF-8 locales (including `en_US.UTF-8` on most systems), `[a-z]` will include the latin letters from `a` to `y` with diacritics but not those of `z` (since `z` sorts before them)...